# When using a Known Sperm Donor is natural insemination (sex) more effective than artificial insemination?

Tags: human-reproduction

There is a community of known sperm donors, who are met by women wanting to get pregnant and provide them sperm without involving a doctor.  Inside of this community a common debate is the difference between artificial insemination (AI), where the sperm donor produces the sample and gives it to the recipient who utilizes it immediately, and Natural Insemination (NI), which is just a politer abbreviation for sex.

It is very common for sperm donors to claim a significantly higher success rate for NI compared to AI. Daily mail references this belief in [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2317617/Sex-return-babies-Websites-offering-women-free-natural-insemination-sperm-donors--YOU-risk-parenting-stranger.html):

> because "natural insemination" is believed to be more than three times more effective than artificial insemination.

I want to know if NI is more effective than AI, and if so what degree of difference there is in odds of conception.  I'm specifically asking in the context of known sperm donors, which means without a bank getting involved, meaning the full sperm sample, not the smaller quantity obtained when purchasing anonymous sperm, and without the sperm being washed/frozen or doing IUI/IVF.  This is also assuming the same number of donations, so controlling for the fact that married couples can have intercourse all month while known donors, of either type, usually have to do their best to time 1-3 donations for peak fertility and thus may suffer slightly from mistiming of donations.  In other words, if sperm enters vagina in its entirety but without actual sexual intercourse what is the difference in success rate.

Unfortunately, I do not think there exists a study on the effectiveness of AI done by known donors.  For the sake of this question I would be willing to accept *the best approximation* of an answer possible, even if there lacks sufficient study to give a 100% conclusive answer.  My goal is to have something from a neutral party that I can provide to women considering known donation which can give them a reasonable answer to what difference, if any, they may see between the two methods to help them decide rather to do NI over AI; I'd rather have the best approximate answer then no answer at all in that case.

I would also appreciate it if the answer giver could include a summary of their results at the top of the answer, something a laymen can read quickly, before going into the more through analysis, again to make this easier on individuals who are not use to skeptics level of analysis who just want a quick answer to the question.

Edit: to those asking how known donor AI it would involve a donation placed in the vagina near the cervix, but not behind it (anything behind the cervix without washing is going to be painful!).  To be exact there are two methods commonly used.  First is the turkey baster method, use a syringe to place the donation in the vagina close to the cervix, the other is use of softcups or diva cups, placing the donation in the cup and then place the cup in the vagina so the donation is held close to the cervix.  I've looked and never found anything useful to state which is more effective, but they seem to be about the same.  The syringe method is functionally equivalent to ICI (Intracervical) done in a doctor's office and so that would likely be the best place to focus on finding studies (though again there is a big difference between a fresh donation and using sperm vials, so studies of ICI using sperm from a bank would not be valid for this use-case).  I would accept answers about any method.

Comment: Do you want comparison to artificially putting the semen in the vagina,  artificially putting the semen in the cervix, or artificially putting the semen in the uterus?

Comment: Is there a sufficiently standard method for this artificial (but non-medical) insemination process that we are comparing to sex? Do they use a literal turkey baster? Special instruments? I can certainly imagine all sorts of variables (tools, techniques, timing, placement, volume, etc) that might be as much or more relevant.

Comment: I don't know anything about it, but am very skeptical of this claim. Seems like the very definition of "motivated reasoning" on the part of donors. I think that makes it a good question for skeptics.SE.

Comment: @BradC I agree, but then any donor making claims that there is no difference are accused as being against sex and having their own motivations.  And of course self-motivation doesn't exclude a claim from being correct.  Thus the goal of getting a source to cite that can't be seen as having a bias either way, like skeptics :)

Comment: I vaguely remember from sex ed all those years ago that a male ejaculation fires semen at up to 30 mph. Mind you, this was from over a decade ago and it could actually be wrong. If this is the case, it's quite likely that a syringe method may come close, but not send it as quickly and the cup method would involve no acceleration thus NI gives that extra boost to reach the egg before the sperm cells die? Highly speculative, but as we've evolved this way, it wouldn't surprise me if it aided in conception.

Comment: For the record, a turkey baster wielded by an amateur is a bad idea, as it can lead to an air bubble in the uterus, which is just asking for an embolism.

Comment: Geoff - I'd like to see a citation for that. I think it's inaccurate.

Comment: @RoryAlsop http://www.healthline.com/health/air-embolism

Comment: That link does not suggest it as a likely cause. Sorry.

Comment: I was pointing out that it was a possibility, if I had felt it was a serious health concern, I would have a) found a better citation, and b) submitted it as part of an answer.

Comment: @BradC The two common insemination methods are the 'turkey baster' method you claimed, and using something called a soft-cup which the donation can be placed into and then can be inserted into the vagina and hold the donation a little closer to the cervix.  As far as I can tell there is no significant difference in either method.  This is functionally equivalent to the way doctors do ICI and I would accept studies on ICI *if* they include the full content of non-frozen ejaculate, instead of a frozen sperm vial from a sperm bank.  IUI/IVF obviously wouldn't qualify.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins turky baster that tries to go past the cervix is a bad idea, but mostly because the body will have an unpleasant reaction to unwashed sperm.  Turkey baster that pushes sperm in front of the cervix is fine, it's open to air anyways after all.  I know quite a few children conceived via that means, I'm even lucky enough to be Godfather or honorary 'Uncle' to a few of them :)

Comment: I don't think the arguments for not using the natural method are against having sex but more of who they want to have sex with. Just because you are okay with having someone as a donor doesn't mean you are okay with or want to have sex with them.

Comment: @JoeW the vast majority of women choose the AI method.  Since the majority of them are also lesbians there is another strong motivation to prefer avoiding NI with a male.  Of course some prefer NI for the sake of enjoyment regardless of success rate.  However, there is a non trivial minority who prefer AI and choose NI specifically because they believe it will increase their odds of success.  This question is specifically targeted towards them, so they know rather choosing NI when they prefer AI will be worth doing for a theoretical increase in odds of success.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back it up? Also just because they are a lesbian doesn't mean that they don't want to have sex just that who they want to have sex with is different. You should stop trying to say not wanting to have sex with a sperm donor is not wanting to have sex.

Comment: @JoeW umm. I never said that not having sex with a sperm donor is the same as not wanting to have sex.  I've met women who identify as lesbians that did prefer to have sex with a sperm donor in fact.  I was only pointing out that *on average* lesbians do tend to be slightly less interested in sex with a man then straight women.  I support women in whatever decision they make about donations or sex, all I want to do is ensure they have accurate information to inform their decision making process.

Comment: Just because you have interacted with some doesn't mean that is the case for all. All I was asking for is evidence to back up the claim rather than what you feel/think. As far as accurate information I am not sure that this question/site will fulfil that need and it seems like you are just trying to advocate for sexual intercourse for sperm donation. And honestly if there is a sperm donation a doctor should be involved anyway.

Comment: It's hard to do such a study in humans. Look what it takes to do one with animals (which don't need to consent). https://aab.copernicus.org/articles/61/459/2018/

Comment: @JoeW: I don't see why this claim should be backed up, it is not relevant for the question. This site seems like a fine place to look for accurate information, good answers tend to provide evidence and links to further reading. Personally I find the last part offensive. If straight couples can make a baby without any doctor present, then why would lesbian couples not be able to do the same? Even if it is artificially inseminated, if there is no significant health risk, then why should people not be allowed to do it themselves?

Comment: @Fizz The idea of looking at animals is a good one.  But that particular study won't help since it's about cryoperserved semen, We know cryoperserving semen lowers overall quality, plus they usually split one ejaculation into multiple samples.

Comment: @Orbit Thank you.  I decided not to respond to JoeW since his objections seemed unclear or to me leading me to suspect his real issue was sperm donation in general, which would make any discussion with him futile.  I appreciate you making the point I would make if I hadn't decided it is best not to continue engagement though.  For what it's worth I'm actually an AI only donor who has sworn to stay a virgin as long as I donate, and asked this question to counter donors attacking me for pointing out there is no evidence NI is better, so his presumptions about me were rather inaccurate.

Comment: @Fizz quick googling shows there are some cases when artificial insemination is used when a male is available to mate with a female due to safety concerns, or in the cases of dogs difficulty of mating due to some dogs breeds being so specialized they have difficulty achieving natural mating any more.  I suspect a study can be found comparing the options of having an available male produce a sample for immediate use vs mating them to a female in one of these cases, which would be a good source to cite.

Comment: @Orbit I am asking for that because of comments from the OP that are claiming that the reason for artificial insemination is because the person doesn't want to have natural sex. That angle leads me to believe that this question is a way to justify trying to get someone to chose the natural method over a doctor performing the artificial method.  It doesn't seem like this question was asked to determine the best method.

Comment: @JoeW: I personally don't care much why a question is asked. If it is a good question that may also help others, it is fine by me. That assumption also doesn't seem to be based on much.

Comment: @dsollen: Thanks for the reply. I did read something about the subject some time ago. I tried to find it again and found this, altough it may not be what you are hoping for: https://theconversation.com/whats-the-point-of-sex-its-communication-at-a-biological-level-67847 There seem to be some links to scientific articles, I haven't checked them.